# How to update a robot visual enable check box in Rviz from a running node (c++)

Tags: ros, c++, rviz, update, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like to hide an existing robot model in Rviz from my running node (c++), I don't want to be checking and unchecking the visual enable option in the RobotModel, I would like to do it dynamically. Is there any way to update the visual of a link or robot when it is being shown in Rviz from the running node that is publishing the TF link values.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231731/how-to-update-a-robot-visual-enable-check-box-in-rviz-from-a-running-node-(c++)/) by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2016-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be great if rviz had a set of topics and services for controlling all aspects of the user interface to the same ability manual clicking does.  But short of that you can create a custom rviz render panel using librviz http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/librviz_tutorial/html/ or http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rviz_python_tutorial/html/ for python.

Any rviz plugin can be added with createDisplay(), and then any property that is normally available through the ui can be changed with subProp()- and you could then hook up your own subscribers or services to change those properties.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1